# How do I make a jQuery script run once a PHP query string has been set?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When a link is clicked I want to append something to the page. However, the link uses PHP like

(Note: This is inside an echo):

```
<a id = 'linkimg1' href='main.php?img1=$img1_id'> [img1 here] </a>
```

I have

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#linkimg1').click(function() {
            $('stuff').appendTo('body')
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I make the link still perform the jQuery script?

Comment: looking for one click ? http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the selector as a parameter. If you don't then the event is bound directly which does not work for dynamic content.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document.body).on('click', '#linkimg1' ,function(){
  $('stuff').appendTo('body')
 });
});
</script>
```

The selector is an essential part to the .on() function

```
.on(eventType, selector, function)
```

jQuery API documentation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: For some reason this wasn't working. I decided to use append() instead and it worked! Not sure why appendTo didn't.

Comment: I'm glad u got it working and in addition to the answer you should also know that $(document.body) is not set in stone. This selector could be any DOM element higher up in the hiearchy that remains in the DOM when ur dynamic content changes. This is kind of like a pathway to your dynamic selector in the on() function

Answer (score 0):

when you are using events handlers to dinamic content use jQuery.on() or jQuery.live() (deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Assign it as an onClick function like so

```
<a id = 'linkimg1' href='main.php?img1=$img1_id' onclick="myFunction()"> [img1 here] </a>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function myFunction() {
            $('#linkimg1').click(function() {
                $('stuff').appendTo('body')
            });
        } 
    });
</script>
```